# django 2.0.4 urls not working

Tags: python, django, django-views

Django suddenly does not seem to be processing urls correctly. I followed part 3 of "Writing your first Django app" again with just a polls view and the urlsconf. It isn't working. What am I missing?

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Here is my polls\urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

whyitsnotworking\urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

whyitsnotworking\settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls',
```

Here is the directory for my polls app:
    migrations
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    **init**.py

I can run the test server:

```
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
April 08, 2018 - 16:25:27
Django version 2.0.4, using settings 'whyitsnotworking.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[08/Apr/2018 16:25:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16348
Not Found: /polls
[08/Apr/2018 16:25:39] "GET /polls HTTP/1.1" 404 1964
```

But get the following error message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls

Using the URLconf defined in whyitsnotworking.urls, Django tried these URL     patterns, in this order:

    admin/

The current path, polls, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the [`include()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#include) around `admin.site.urls`, because you're calling the direct pythonic path towards the urls module in `admin.site`, you don't need to use `include()`. You only need to use `include()` if you want to tell Django the path towards your `urls.py` file that you want to include, and that's usually a string that exists in formats similar to `<appname>.urls`.

Comment: although my issue was caused by my not reading filepaths, this did actually help correct the info in the django docs, so thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had the urls file in mysite\urls.py, not mysite\mysite\urls.py

What a dummy!